# SQLite not inserting expected values in Qt

Tags: qt, sqlite

I'm having some troubles inserting values in my `SQLite database`

This is how I create the DB:

```
if(query.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visitorItemsV4 (channelID, itemId, itemName, itemPic, itemPrice, itemMeta);")) {
    qDebug() << "Table `visitorItemsV4` created.";
}
```

And this is how I insert a new item:

```
if (db.isOpen()) {    
    qDebug() << itemId;
    qDebug() << itemName;
    qDebug() << itemPic;
    qDebug() << itemPrice;

    QSqlQuery query(db);

    ret = query.exec(QString("insert or replace into visitorItemsV4 values ('%1', '%2', '%3', '%4', '%5', '%6');")
    .arg(channel).arg(itemId).arg(itemName).arg(itemPic).arg(itemPrice).arg(itemPrice));

    qDebug() << query.lastError();

    if (ret) {
        qDebug() << "saved item";
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `itemPrice` always gets the value of `%5` and `itemMeta` gets a value of `%6`

`itemPrice` variable contains `499` so I would expect that to be the value of `itemPrice` and `itemMeta`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is that a typo? You got a duplicate of `arg(itemPrice)`...

Comment: I want `itemPrice` to be inserted into both `itemPrice` and `itemMeta` column

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by `The problem is that the itemPrice always gets the value of %5 and itemMeta gets a value of %6`.

Comment: When I look inside my database with my DB explorer. I can see that the row i just inserted has the values: channel1, id123, theItemName12, thePicture, %5, %6 that means for some reason the two last arg's are setting a value of %5 and %6 instead of the contents of the variable `itemPrice`

Comment: Try to build an interim QString variable and print that out after the construction, but before the exec. Anyway, you could also use binding.

Comment: Settings `itemPrice = "499";` before the exec still results in same problem :/

Comment: That is not what I meant. ;) Create the whole string with .arg() and all that before the query. Also, what does lastError() print out? It should just work. bindvalue is just a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never try to create SQL commands by putting values directly into the string; this not only creates formatting problems, but allows SQL injection.

Use parameters instead:

```c
query.prepare("insert or replace into visitorItemsV4 values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
query.bindValue(0, channel);
query.bindValue(1, itemId);
query.bindValue(2, itemName);
query.bindValue(3, itemPic);
query.bindValue(4, itemPrice);
query.bindValue(5, itemPrice);
ret = query.exec();
```

Comment: @FinalContest What happens when the item name contains `'` or `%4`? What about blobs? Ever heard of [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)?

Comment: @Alosyius: I do not understand how "this work perfectly". It should not even compile. ;-)

Comment: @FinalContest What exactly do you think is wrong syntax in this code?

Comment: Please do test your code before submitting, or leave a disclaimer that you submit untested code. Either way, `Never try to create SQL commands by putting values directly into the string` is the bigger issue since it is conceptually wrong. See my answer that it works (and should work) fine for me.